# Exercise 5.12 from Casella’s Book

Tags: probability-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Any hint for this exercise from Casella´s book:

[image]

I tried with Cauchy Schwarz, Minkovsky  Inequality but I am stuck.

I also tried to calculate the Variance but its not clear that they are independent.

Any help?

Comment: When you say $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample from a population it is understood that they are independent random variables. Variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variances.

Comment: We have $Y_1 \leq Y_2$ pointwise, there you have "an inequality between them."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\frac 1 n$. Hence it has same distribution as $\frac 1 {\sqrt n} X_1$. It follows that $EY_1=\frac 1 {\sqrt n}E|X_1|$. On the other hand $EY_2=\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} E|X_i|=E|X_1|$. Of course $EY_1 \leq EY_2$.

Answer (score 2):

By the triangle inequality
$$
Y_1\leq Y_2
$$
whence $EY_1\leq EY_2$